# Question about simple authorization

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, authorization

I am using Devise for authentication, and I only need a simple admin or use check for a few controllers.  I'm new to rails, so I'm trying to do this the right way.  I've basically added a boolean admin field to the user model and added this method

```
  def is_admin?
    admin == 1
  end
```

Then I simply modified the controller action to this

```
  def new
    if current_user.nil? || !current_user.is_admin?
        flash[:notice] = "You do not have permission to view this page"
        redirect_to "/gyms"
      else
      @gym = Gym.new

      respond_to do |format|
        format.html # new.html.erb
        format.xml  { render :xml => @gym }
      end
    end
  end
```

So this solution works, but should I be doing this a different way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will work but I probably would not recommend this solution for anything else than a small scale project. Over time, if you perform authorization checks within your controllers, your code is going to become bloated and difficult to manage.

Instead I would consider using an authorization module such as [Cancan](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan) which centralizes your authorization rules in one place and thus decouples your application logic from your authorization logic. The end result is cleaner and more maintainable code.

With Cancan in place, your code might look like this:

```
# app/controllers/gyms_controller.rb
class GymsController < ApplicationController
  load_and_autorize_resource

  def new
      respond_to do |format|
        format.html # new.html.erb
        format.xml  { render :xml => @gym }
      end
    end
  end
end

# app/models/Ability.rb
can :create, Gym do |trip|
  user.is_admin?
end
```